# Is html5 and css3 far enough along to create a web app in it completely and there would be a userbase?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a web app with a desired release date of fall-winter 2011. I love the capabilities of html5 and css3 and was wondering if I developed it in that completely if there would be a userbase for the app.

Comment: No one uses an application because of the technology used to build it.  There will be a userbase if you create compelling content that people want to use.

Comment: Google thinks so, but who's heard of them?

Comment: @Wooble I guess I should have clarified it. Will enough people have a browser that can render html5 and css3

Comment: @msw good point (and microsoft with bing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your target date, you shouldn't have any problem releasing a standards compliant HTML5/CSS3 site.

You already have Firefox/Chrome/Safari/IE9 that you can test against and it's only Fall of 2010. By this time in 2011, enough people should have upgraded to some compatible version of their chosen browser that you'll have a good sized user base.

Comment: Be careful if you're app targets business users.  Sure home consumers will have probably upgraded by then, but a fair whack of business are still on IE 6.

Comment: ...or if it targets people casually browsing at the office

Comment: @Michael Shimmins and @Martin good point. The app I am thinking of currently does not target business users

Comment: @robertc don't worry, that is actually where it will be aimed at mainly with it starting as a web app that is made specifically for iphone and android and works with pcs and then moving to where the web app is mainly for pcs and there would be iphone and android apps available that offer much more functionality (using the gps push notifications etc.)